# Is there a (semi-)automatic way to use unmanaged C++ DLLs with C# without COM?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

I have a third-party unmanaged DLL which was written in C++. This library contains a lot of classes with a lot of methods. The library is not COM-based; trying `tlbimp` just gets me the error that the DLL is not a valid type library.
I managed to use functionality from this DLL from managed C++ though, and writing a wrapper DLL which delegates everything to the unmanaged one and using it from C# works fine. However, the third-party DLL is big, so I would have to re-implement the whole interface by hand to delegate all functionality to the unmanaged DLL.
Is there a way to simplify this? What comes in mind first because I am coming from the JVM universe is reflection, but C++ does not support it.

I do not have the source code of the unmanaged DLL, only the DLL itself, its associated `.lib` and a bunch of header files. Functionality of this DLL is exported via `__declspec(dllexport)`.

Comment: You should take a look at PInvoke and Marshaling. It should be possible to use your dll.

Comment: There is [swig](http://www.swig.org/)... but it is *complex*

Comment: I am currently trying swig but I figured I have to dig into it quite heavily. I added a simple .i file which just `#include`s the header but nothing gets exported to the generated C# classes (they are empty). I think I will go with PInvoke.

Comment: @rabejens You can't use directly pinvoke if you need to `new` a C++ class and then `delete` it.

Comment: I figured this out, too. I think the best solution is indeed manually writing a wrapper. At least, I currently only need a fraction of the functionality of the third-party DLL, so I can adaptively add new stuff.

Comment: For big integration projects I'd go with C++/CLI, but as you've said, you'll have to define a managed interface yourself on top on the unmanaged one. Still, it's easier than P/Invoke when you have header files.